# Pass only valid characters in java

Tags: java, string

I want to do something like this:

```
String myString="123EDCBAabcde";
myString=myString.passValidChars("ABCDE");

now myString is "EDCBA"
```

Is there already a function which only passes the valid characters and removes the others? If not what is the best way to do this?

Best Regards.

Comment: What you want actually ?

Comment: I want to strip illegal characters of a string. But I only have the valid characters list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[^ABCDE.]+", "");
```

Comment: Much slower than other ways. You should at least add `+` at the end to cut down on number of iterations of `matcher.find()` and `matcher.appendReplacement`.

Comment: Thank you Wojtek! This is the solution for me. For performance questions: I don't need this code to be fast.

Comment: Charlie Brown - I find it useful to try to write optimal code even when it's not needed, because it's habit forming. Of course I'm not talkin about profiling and deep optimizations that would require time. I'm talking about cases where optimization requires trivial investment (in this case a single character at the end of regex, another case would be ordering clauses in `||` and `&&` sentences so that lightest expressions are evaluated first). I see Wojtek amended his solution.

Comment: @U Mad +1, Can anybody explain what the . (dot) is for in the regex?

Comment: In this case it's a literal dot. It's a typo. This regex will match any characters that are not ABCDE or dot.

Answer (score 3):

This is trival to implement.

- Start with an empty StringBuilder.
- Iterate through each char of `myString`.
- If the char is contained in the String of valid chars, add it to the StringBuilder.
- Convert the StringBuilder to a String.
- Done.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I'm going to implement if there is no other elegant/ready solution.

Comment: I don't understand how its better than O(len(str)). Wojtek's answer seems just as efficient as this one.

Comment: @JB Nizet I added an answer with your solution. I'am worry about the 'indexOf' which will need in the worst case to iterate over all the String...

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: First, use charAt to get each char rather than toCharArray. It avoids a copy of the whold string. Second, I doubt the indexOf performance penalty is something to worry about. No need for premature optimization. Especially if the valid chars are few.

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "123EDCBAabcde";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABCDE]");
Matcher mach = pattern.matcher(string);

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
while(mach.find()){
    str.append(mach.group());
}
string = str.toString(); // Now string is "EDCBA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava library (google collections) has the exact class you need: `CharMatcher`

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/Guava_for_Netflix_.pdf

Pages 12 up to 19.

Comment: Thank you, I can only use Java SE.

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]").matcher(myString).replaceAll("")`

Answer (score 0):

Related to @JB Nizet answer:

```
    static String passValidChar(String in, String validChar){
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c : in.toCharArray()){
            if(validChar.indexOf(String.valueOf(c)) != -1){
                strBuilder.append(c);
            }
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(passValidChar("123EDCBAabcde", "EDCBA"));    
    }
```